# need quick gstreamer application to test if qtdemux is working

Tags: gstreamer

Can someone give me a quick gstreamer application to test if qtdemux is working. It needs to output to a filesink not imagesink as this is on a server with no gui.
I seem to have it working via gst-launch, but when compiling an application it does not seem to work.

I have tried the following,

```
caps = gst_caps_new_simple("video/x-raw-yuv",
                      "format", GST_TYPE_FOURCC, GST_MAKE_FOURCC ('I', '4', '2', '0'),
                      "width", G_TYPE_INT, 384,
                      "height", G_TYPE_INT, 216,
                      "framerate", GST_TYPE_FRACTION, 25, 1,
                      NULL);
```

Thx Art

Answer (score 0):

You can test everything from gst-launch like so:

`gst-launch filesrc location=test.mov ! qtdemux name=demux  demux.audio_00 ! decodebin ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! autoaudiosink   demux.video_00 ! queue ! decodebin ! ffmpegcolorspace ! videoscale ! autovideosink`

More info on [qtdemux](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good-plugins/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-qtdemux.html)